# how to make Javascript/jQuery autoclicking a single button with intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, setinterval

I want this button to press itself an unlimited amount of time every second after I have pressed it once.

Here is my example of the code which isn't working and I can't figure out why since I'm still new with Javascript and jQuery.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['attack'])) {
$_SESSION['hero_experience'] = $_SESSION['hero_experience']+1;
}

print_r($_SESSION['hero_experience']);
?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#attack").click(function(){
                    setInterval(function(){document.getElementById("#attack").click();},1000);
  });
});
        </script>

        <form action="#" method="POST">
<input id="attack" type="submit" name="attack" value="attack">
        </form>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your logic, it doesn't make sense for the click function to create an interval that calls the click function. You will end up with lots and lots of endless intervals very quickly! Perhaps you want `setTimeout()` in this case

Comment: Currently I am trying to make a php RPG game with automatic battle. Currently works with a button but that is why I need this code to work.

Comment: And I am trying to tell you it isn't going to work the way you expect. Either take my advice, or just do it your way until you realize the problem on your own

Comment: I chose setTimeout as you recommended me to do and it works just as I expected, thank you for your help musefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use `#` with id in `document.getElementById` as it getElementById takes id of element with `#`. You have to give `#` with jQuery selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SdKU7/1/)**

*Change*

```
document.getElementById("#attack").click();
```

*To*

```
document.getElementById("attack").click();
```

*OR*

```
$("#attack").click();
```

*OR*

```
$("#attack").trigger("click");
```

Change code to

```
setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("attack").click();
}, 5000);


$("#attack").click(function () {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: for some reason all your examples still ain't working for me.
is there something wrong with my script source or anything else?

Comment: perfect, it is autoclicking with the latest example of yours exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Its always good to have a hold on the timer objects .. 
Also since you are using jquery, you can use that to evoke click events

```
<script>
var myTimerObj = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#attack").click(function(){
                  myTimerObj =  setInterval(function(){
                              $("#attack").click();
                              },1000);
  });
});

function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myTimerObj);
}
</script>
```

when ever you want to stop the timer, you can call the myStopFunction . Hope this helps optimize you code performance :)

Comment: That is very helpful arunartzoom, that was some extras I didn't think about.

But still it's like none of the examples given is working for me. But yet the examples seems perfect. I have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Again, using `setInterval` causes a problem. your `myTimerObj` will be constantly overwritten with each new `setInterval` that is created, and there will be lots of them!